# Webflow grid layout

Tags: flexbox, grid, webflow

I cannot find how is this done, I want to take the layout straight, I mean no one box above the other.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cR6J.jpg)

I tried to check the grid and flex customizations

Answer (score 0):

In that screenshot you're likely seeing alternating item layouts.
My guess is the odd-numbered items have a margin-top styling.

See the [Webflow-U docs](https://university.webflow.com/lesson/style-first-last-odd-even-items-in-your-cms#:%7E:text=Odd%20and%20Even%20items,properties%20in%20the%20Style%20panel) on this to change that setting to whatever you like.